# A single array input in a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{

    int d, a[3][3] = {{2, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11}};
    for (d = 0; d < 5; d++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n\n", d, a[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i'm getting the output

```
a[0] = 6422048
a[1] = 6422060
a[2] = 6422072
a[3] = 6422084
a[4] = 6422096
```

i'm curious about where did those values come from, and why is it incrementing by 12?

Comment: it's technically UB for `d == 4` and so on

Answer (score 2):

They are pointers. AND the outputs are increased by 12 next because size of int[3] is 12 bytes.

Comment: ... and using `%d` to print the pointers isn't correct. `%p` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is array of arrays, when you are trying to output you are printing array. Arrays are like pointers, it will give you an address of array. Another problem is, you are accessing your 2D array like 1D array, your array is 3x3 matrix but you are accessing to its 3th and 4th index with `d` variable. What you want to do is:

```
    for (int i = 0; d < 3; ++j) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %i\n\n", i, j , a[i][j]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not so much into C, but I don't think arrays "are like pointers" in C. I think they _decay_ into pointers when passed as arguments to functions, like `printf`, but, I could be wrong. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @TedLyngmo actually you are right, I just wanted to tell that by printing array will give you an address like in pointers.

Comment: I get that. I don't know C well enough to say that the address of the array is guaranteed. `printf` has expectations. `%d` and a pointer ... not a perfect match. In my world, that's undefined behavior. Perhaps not in C.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile with `-Wall -Wextra` (always do that) you'll get the answer:

```
$ gcc k.c -Wall -Wextra
k.c: In function ‘main’:
k.c:9:26: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    9 |         printf("a[%d] = %d\n\n", d, a[d]);
      |                         ~^          ~~~~
      |                          |           |
      |                          int         int *
      |                         %ls
```

It says that `a[d]` has type `int*` which means that it's a pointer.